# IOperation Filter Change in Swashbuckle v5.5.3

Tags: asp.net, swagger, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I trying to Add two custom MediaType to same method.
for adding this task we can use [Produces()] attribute, but if we want to have two GET method in same controller we get this error in swagger

> SwaggerGeneratorException: Conflicting method/path combination "GET api/authors/{authorId}/books/{bookId}" for actions - Library.API.Controllers.BooksController.GetBook (Library.API),Library.API.Controllers.BooksController.GetBookWithConcatenatedAuthorName (Library.API). Actions require a unique method/path combination for Swagger/OpenAPI 3.0. Use ConflictingActionsResolver as a workaround

in Swashbuckle v5 beta we can use this IOperationFilter and add custom MediaType schema and use this code

```
 public class GetBookOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (operation.OperationId != "GetBook")
        {
            return;
        }

        operation.Responses[StatusCodes.Status200OK.ToString()].Content.Add(
            "application/vnd.marvin.bookwithconcatenatedauthorname+json",
            new OpenApiMediaType()
            {
                Schema = context.SchemaRegistry.GetOrRegister(typeof(BookWithConcatenatedAuthorName))
            });
    }
}
```

but we can not use this code in Swashbuckle v5.6.3

please help me to resolve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Replece This Code And Solved My Problem.

```
if (context.ApiDescription.ActionDescriptor.RouteValues["action"] != "GetBook")
            {
                return;
            }

        var schema = context.SchemaGenerator.GenerateSchema(typeof(BookWithConcatenatedAuthorName), context.SchemaRepository);
       
            if (operation.Responses.Any(a=> a.Key==StatusCodes.Status200OK.ToString()))
            {
            operation.Responses[StatusCodes.Status200OK.ToString()].Content.Add(
                "application/vnd.marvin.bookwithconcatenatedauthorname+json",
                new OpenApiMediaType() { Schema = schema });
            }
```